# Extjs layout extension causing error in ext-all.js

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to learn Extjs and I am immediately coming up with an issue.  My Html has `ext-base.js` and `ext-all.js` correctly included.  I then have the following in my js file:

```
Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = '<%= Url.Content("~/Content/ext/images/default/s.gif") %>';
Ext.ns('MyNamespace');

Ext.onReady(function() {
    alert("onReady() fired");
});
```

So far everything is working, no errors and the alert is thrown correctly.  I then add the following code after onReady:

```
MyNamespace.BaseLayout = Ext.Extend(Ext.Viewport({
    layout: 'border',
    items: [
        new Ext.BoxComponent({
            region: 'north',
            height: 32,
            autoEl: {
                tag: 'div',
                html: '<p>North</p>'
            }
        })
    ]
}));
```

This causes the following javascript error in chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'addEvents'       ext-all.js:7
Ext.Component       ext-all.js:7
Ext.apply.extend.K       ext-base.js:7
Ext.apply.extend.K       ext-base.js:7
Ext.apply.extend.K       ext-base.js:7
(anonymous function)       MyApp.js:13 (pointing to the Ext.Extend line)
```

If I take the Viewport code and put it directly into the OnReady function it (like the following)

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var bl = new Ext.Viewport({
        layout: 'border',
        items: [
        new Ext.BoxComponent({
            region: 'north',
            height: 32,
            autoEl: {
                tag: 'div',
                html: '<p>North</p>'
            }
        })
    ]
    });
});
```

It works.  Can anyone clue me in to what I am doing wrong with the Extend method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bit more complicated example of what you're trying to accomplish. I'd strongly suggest taking a look at Saki's [3 part series](http://blog.extjs.eu/know-how/writing-a-big-application-in-ext/) in building large apps with ExtJS, it'll help you understand how it use extend properly to create re-usable components.

```
Ext.ns('MyNamespace');

MyNamespace.BaseLayout = Ext.extend(Ext.Viewport, {
    initComponent:function() {
        var config = {
            layout: 'border',
            items: [
                new Ext.BoxComponent({
                    region: 'north',
                    height: 32,
                    autoEl: {
                        tag: 'div',
                        html: '<p>North</p>'
                    }
                })
            ]
        };
        Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));

        MyNamespace.BaseLayout.superclass.initComponent.apply(this,arguments);
    }//end initComponent

});

//this will give you an xtype to call this component by.
Ext.reg('baselayout',MyNamespace.BaseLayout);

Ext.onReady(function() {
    new MyNamespace.BaseLayout({});
});
```

Comment: Just a note -- there is no need to override onRender unless there's going to be some actual code in it. (Just in case someone comes along later and copy/pastes from this answer.)

Comment: Yep, I got the code I wrote from reading Saki's blog, but when I went back to use it as a reference I apparently thought there were parenthesis around the `ViewPort` call.  Stupid me :).  Thanks!

Comment: I see, this code is a bit different than the tutorial I was looking at before.  Thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Answer (score 2):

To fix your code, the issue is simply bad syntax in the Extend statement.  You need a comma after Ext.Viewport, not an extra () pair:

```
MyNamespace.BaseLayout = Ext.Extend(Ext.Viewport, {
    layout: 'border',
    items: [
        new Ext.BoxComponent({
            region: 'north',
            height: 32,
            autoEl: {
                tag: 'div',
                html: '<p>North</p>'
            }
        })
    ]
});
```

However, I'd suggest taking @r-dub's advice and reading up more on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Doh, misread the Extend syntax when reading that Saki blog.  I already read it, I just mis-read the syntax from it!

Comment: This doesn't work.  This causes the following error:  `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'Extend'`

Comment: That has nothing to do with this code, which is correct as shown. That usually is an issue with how you've set up your includes.

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS recommend the use of define instead of extend. Here is how a similar example works with define:

```
 Ext.define('Grid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    config: {          
        height: 2000        
    },

    applyHeight: function (height) {           
            return height;
    }       
});

new Grid({
    store: store,
    columns: [{
        text: 'Department',
        dataIndex: 'DepartmentName',
        renderer: function (val, meta, record) {
            return '<a href="DepartmentEmployees/' + record.data.ID + '">' + record.data.DepartmentName + '</a>';
        },
        width: 440,
        flex: 1,
        filter: 'string',
        sortable: true,
        hideable: false
    }, {
        text: 'Department Code',
        dataIndex: 'DepartmentKey',
        width: 100,
        flex: 1,
        filter: 'string',
        sortable: true,
        hideable: false
    }, {
        text: 'Main Phone',
        dataIndex: 'MainPhone',
        flex: 1,
        filter: 'string',
        sortable: true,
        hideable: false
    }, {
        text: 'Room',
        dataIndex: 'RoomLocation',
        flex: 1,
        filter: 'string',
        sortable: true,
        hideable: false
    }, {
        text: 'Hideway Location',
        dataIndex: 'HideawayLocation',
        flex: 1,
        filter: 'string',
        sortable: true,
        hideable: false
    }, {
        text: 'Hideway Phone',
        dataIndex: 'HideawayPhone',
        flex: 1,
        filter: 'string',
        sortable: true,
        hideable: false
    }, {
        text: 'Has OEC',
        dataIndex: 'OECFlag',
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        width: 50,
        filter: {
            type: 'boolean',
            active: true
        },
        flex: 1,
        sortable: true,
        hideable: false
    },
       {
           text: 'Action',
           dataIndex: 'ID',
           renderer: function (value) {
               return '<a href="DepartmentEdit/' + value + '">Edit</a>';
           },
           hideable: false
       }],
    forceFit: false,
    split: true,
    renderTo: 'departmentSearchGrid',
    frame: false,
    width: 1300,
    plugins: ['gridfilters']
});
```

I used the following post as a reference:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/core_concepts/classes.html